# XAML controls not recognised in code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a strange problem where a XAML control is not visible in the code behind.  Here is a sample of the XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvtest" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,20,0,0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>     
            <StackPanel>                                
                <WebView Name="contentView" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Name="testtxt" Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
```

In the code behind:

`this.lvtest` is recognised, but:

`this.contentView` and `this.testtxt` are both not.

I've also tried `x:Name`.

I'm clearly missing something obvious here, I just can't see what.

EDIT:

To clarify, the textbox control was going to be used to display some formatted text based on the binding, but what I have discovered is that the text is HTML formatted ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx) suggests using a WebView control).  As far as I can see I need to `NavigateToString` to use the WebView control, and so can't bind it as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're missing is that the elements defined in a DataTemplate may be on the page any number of times, which can even change while running.  Which one should be linked to the `contentView` field?  There's no good way to answer that, so it simply doesn't create a `contentView` field.

To put it another way, you're not defining that the page includes those elements, you're declaring a template from which .NET can create elements.

If you let us know how you're trying to use it, we might be able to suggest another way.

Edit: Something like this might work for you:

```
<WebView Loaded="contentView_Loaded" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" />
```

Then in the code:

```
void contentView_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var contentView = (WebView)sender;
    var dataContext = (YourDataType)contentView.DataContext;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question.  Basically I'm trying to display formatted HTML within a bound list (that's what the TextBlock was originally for).

Comment: That doesn't work, but you've put me on the right track - thanks

Answer (score 3):

They are hidden because they are inside a template control.

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/29ecc8ee-26ee-4331-8f97-35ff9d3e6886

```
<ListView  Name="listview">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >

            <TextBlock Name="textYear" Text="{Binding Year}" />

                <TextBlock  Text="  " />

             <TextBlock Name="textDayOffWeek" Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />

                </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <s:DateTime >1/2/2007</s:DateTime>

    <s:DateTime >1/3/2008</s:DateTime>

    <s:DateTime >1/5/2007</s:DateTime>

    <s:DateTime >1/6/2006</s:DateTime>

</ListView>

    <Button Width="180" Height="30" Content="Find TextBlock in DataTemplate" Click="FindElement" />

    </StackPanel>
```

In the code behind:

```
  private void FindElement(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        // get the current selected item

        ListViewItem item = listview.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listview.SelectedIndex) as ListViewItem;

        TextBlock textYear = null;

        if (item != null)

        {

            //get the item's template parent

            ContentPresenter templateParent = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(item);

            //get the DataTemplate that TextBlock in.

            DataTemplate dataTemplate = listview.ItemTemplate;

            if (dataTemplate != null && templateParent != null)

            {

                 textYear = dataTemplate.FindName("textYear", templateParent) as TextBlock;

            }

            if (textYear != null)

            {

                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Current item's Year is:{0}", textYear.Text));

            }

        }



    }

    private static T GetFrameworkElementByName<T>(FrameworkElement referenceElement) where T : FrameworkElement

    {

        FrameworkElement child = null;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(referenceElement); i++)

        {

            child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(referenceElement, i) as FrameworkElement;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(child);

            if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))

            { break; }

            else if (child != null)

            {

                child = GetFrameworkElementByName<T>(child);

                if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))

                {

                    break;

                }

            }

        }

        return child as T;

    }
```